# Changing colour of tkinter button python 33

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter, colors

I'm trying to get a button to change colour to let the user know that they have pressed the button. I've seen other questions like this but none of them helped. I am quite new at coding but have been reading guidance books on tkinter and all the modules with it. Yet i can't change it's colour

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import time


class Window(Frame):

def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master = master
    self.init_window()
    self.master.title("Conversion System")

def init_window(self):
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    menu = Menu(self.master)
    self.master.config(menu=menu)
    file = Menu(menu)
    file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_close)
    menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)

    conversionTab = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Conversions", menu=conversionTab)
    conversionTab.add_checkbutton(label="Binary To Denary", command=self.binary2denary)
    conversionTab.add_checkbutton(label="Hexadecimal to Denary", command=self.binary2denary)
    conversionTab.add_command(label="System Info", command=self.SystemInfo)


    # creating a button instance
    userChoice  = Label(text="Chose a converter!")
    userChoice.pack(padx=0, pady=0, side=TOP)
    b2dButton = Button(self, text="Binary to Denary", bg="white", fg="black", command=self.binary2denary)
    b2dButton.pack(padx=10, pady=5, side=TOP)
    hexaButton = Button(self, text="Hexadecimal to Denary", bg="white", fg="black", command=self.hexa2denary)
    hexaButton.pack(padx=10, pady=5, side=TOP)
    SystemInfo = Button(self, text="System Info", bg="white", fg="black", command=self.SystemInfo)
    SystemInfo.pack(padx=10, pady=5, side=TOP)
    quitButton = Button(self, text="Quit", bg="red", fg="black", command=self.client_close)
    quitButton.pack(padx=5, pady=20, side=BOTTOM)

def SystemInfo(self):
    os.startfile("Code")

def hexa2denary(self):
    print("s")

def binary2denary(self):
    print("s")
    self.Button.configure(bg="Green")
```

The error code:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1442, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Python/Converter/Main.py", line 49, in binary2denary
    self.Button.configure(bg="Green")
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'Button'
```

Comment: error message shows where is problem and what is problem - check it in code and you will see your mistake.

Comment: BTW: edit question and use button `{}` to correctly format code (next time do it also with error message)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `self.Button` but `b2dButton` in which you want to change color
but you have to use `self.b2dButton` to have access in all functions

Inside `init_window()` you need

```
self.b2dButton = Button(...)
self.b2dButton.pack
```

Inside method `binary2denary()` you need

```
self.b2dButton.configure(bg="Green")
```

---

BTW: error message shows it

```
File "C:/Users/Robert/Desktop/Robert's Python/Converter/Main.py", line 49, in binary2denary
    self.Button.configure(bg="Green")
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'Button'
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'b2dButton' still given thjs error